# Выравнять таблицу на всю высоту страницы и по центру

Tags: html, css

Доброго всем времени суток

```
// посностью рабочий HTML код
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<style>
html, body { height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<table style="border:10px solid red; width:900px; height:100%;">
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align:top;">
13423545345
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Тут мне захотелось добавить в верхнюю строку <!DOCTYPE html> получилось:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<style>
html, body { height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<table style="border:10px solid red; width:050%; height:100%;">
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align:top;">
13423545345
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

И как всегда это бывает все поехало. Перестало работать растягивание страницы на всю высоту страницы. В чем дело? Тэг <center> и </center> мешает. Если его убрать - все работает, но проблема, таблица выровнена не по центру. Т.е. или одно или другое. Или высота 100% или выравнивание по центру.

Вопрос прост. Как совместить желаемое? Высота таблички должна быть 100%, и выравнивание по центру страницы.

P.s. Давно хотел задать вопрос уровня школьника но стеснялся. Даже обидно как то такое спрашивать. День пришел ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- не было title -->
<title>aaa</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">

<!-- не было type -->
<style type="text/css">
html, body { height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px; }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<!-- center убрать, добавить margin:auto в table -->
<table style="border:10px solid red; margin:auto; width:50%; height:100%;">
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align:top;">
13423545345
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо klopp, а можно тогда узнать следующее. Center - предполагает, что можно его заменить скажем на right. А вот в случае с margin:auto - такое не прокатывает. Как в этом случае быть?

Comment: В рамках HTML5 (что указано в DTD) ни тег center, ни тег align в таблице не имеют никакого смысла вообще. Их просто нет в спецификации. Чтобы прижать таблицу вправо можно использовать, например, float:right в стилях для table.